# How to get all output values from map variable in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I'm trying to extract id variable from child module to pass it to another child module. My output block in `networking` module is looking like

```
output "database_subnets_properties" {
  description = "List of all* Database Subnets Properties"
  value = tomap({
    for k, subnet in aws_subnet.database : k => {
      arn = subnet.arn
      id  = subnet.id
    }
  })
}
```

I need to pass IDs from this output to lambda `vpc_config` block.
VPC config block looks like

```
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = var.database_subnets_ids
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.for_lambda.id]
  }
```

If I pass them like

```
database_subnets_ids = [module.networking.database_subnets_properties[0].id, module.networking.database_subnets_properties[1].id, module.networking.database_subnets_properties[2].id]
```

in main.tf, it's working.

I can't find a solution how to improve this code with implementing loop or something like that.
Could you please advise?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [splat expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat):

```
database_subnets_ids = values(module.networking.database_subnets_properties)[*].id
```

Comment: Hi Marcin
Thanks for reach me out, I was trying to do this way, but terraform sent me this error:
`Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Missing map element
│ 
│   on main.tf line 82, in module "microservices":
│   82:   database_subnets_ids = module.networking.database_subnets_properties[*].id #local.database_subnets_ids[*].id
│ 
│ This map does not have an element with the key "id".`
But key "id" is present in this mapping, I showed it in the original question body